# Call Methods in Extension Delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

Is it possible to call methods in the extension delegate from a other IntefaceController in general?

Something like:

```
InterfaceController *interfaceController =[[InterfaceController alloc] init]; 
interfaceController callMethod
```

My Interface Controller

```
    #import "InterfaceController.h"
#import "OrdinaryEventRow.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>

@interface InterfaceController()    

@implementation InterfaceController

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    //Configure interface objects here.

-(void)doSomething {
    [self presentControllerWithName:@"goalView" context:nil];
}

@end
```

ExtensionDelegate:

```
#import "ExtensionDelegate.h"
#import "InterfaceController.h"
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
#import "setGoal.h"

@implementation ExtensionDelegate


//Handle Local Notification Actions
-(void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UNNotification *)localNotification{

    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"action"]){
        //Setup WCSession
        if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
            [[WCSession defaultSession] setDelegate:self];
            [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];

            //Get the value from slider
            NSString *someString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                    stringForKey:@"Update"];
            NSString *Update = @"Update";
            NSDictionary *applicationData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[Update] forKeys:@[@"Update"]];
            //Send Message to the iPhone (handle over the goal value)
            [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:applicationData
                                       replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {
                                           //handle reply from iPhone app here
                                       }
                                       errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                                           //catch any errors here
                                       }
             ];
        }
    }



//If Goal Setting was clicked
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"action3"]){
        //here I want to call doSomething from InterfaceController

    }
}
```

So I just want to call a method defined in the InterfaceController from ExtensionDelegate.

Comment: You want to call a custom function implemented in delegate from another controller?

Comment: Well I have a method in my InterfaceController like -(void)doSomething. And I want to call this Method from my ExtensionDelegate class.

Comment: can you share the ExtensionDelegate class and interfaceController code ...

Comment: Sure i added it - see above

Comment: ah yes .. create instance of your class and then call the method where you want or  Use static class which will allow you to call the method without creating instance of the class ..

Comment: I tried. but: InterfaceController *myClass = [[Interface alloc]init];
        [Interface doSomething]; gives me ecx_bad_error ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to init a `WKInterfaceController` from the `ExtensionDelegate` and call a method on it. If the controller you are trying to call a method is the root controller, you can get the `rootController` from the `WKExtension` in the `ExtensionDelegate` cast it and call a method on it.

```
// Objective-C
if ([WKExtension shared].rootController isKindOfClass:[InitialInterfaceController class]) {
    (InitialInterfaceController *)[WKExtension shared].rootController customMethod];
}

// Swift
    if let root = WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController as? InitialInterfaceController {
    root.customMethod()
}
```

* My objective-c is a little rusty so if there is a syntax error there please update or let me know in the comments and I can edit.

From your code example, you are trying to do an action based on a local notification so the best thing to do is handle the notification in the Interface Controller itself. Depending on what watchOS you are using

watchOS 3

[handleAction(withIdentifier:for:) reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1648286-handleaction)

watchOS 2

[handleAction(withIdentifier:for:) reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619516-handleaction)

Important note here for these methods to be called your extension delegate does not implement the handleAction(withIdentifier:for:) method, WatchKit calls this method on your app’s root interface controller to respond to button taps in your notification interface.

Comment: Ok that was what i thougt. I was confused because in iOS there is no problem to call a method in the AppDelegate. Anyway, so I replaced the handleAction into the ViewController. Thanks!

Comment: @ASP_Soldier no problem! If you believe my answer has answered your question, then mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: what if its not a root controller then how we can call method